# Is this a supported Jenkins Master-slave configuration?

Tags: jenkins, hudson, master-slave

We have a master Jenkins running on a Linux system. The same master is attached as node using "Launch slave via execution of a command on the master". It has the same FS root as the JENKINS_HOME. The command is ssh "machine_name" "shell_script"

The shell script gets the latest slave.jar and runs it.

The master has 0 executors. The node has been given 7. I'm seeing weird behavior in the builds, like workspaces being deleted once a day, etc. I'm not sure if this is related to the way the Jenkins Master-slave is configured.

Any ideas if this is a supported configuration?

Comment: Why would you want to attach a master as a slave to itself in the first place? What are you hoping to gain from this?

Comment: The idea behind it is for all nodes to start with the same environment setup. The shell script used to launch slave.jar, sets certain environment variables. They don't want to add that to the script that launches the master.

Comment: Using the master as a slave is a valid configuration. However, I would change the FS root for the slaves to be some directory other than JENKINS_HOME.